# How to type hint variable that is initially None but is guaranteed to get a value

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a class variable as shown below:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value: MyOtherClass | None = None
        self.initialize_value()

    def initialize_value(self):
        self.value = MyOtherClass()

    def use_value(self):
        return self.value.used
```

`self.value` is guaranteed to be initialized as an instance of `MyOtherClass` before being used in `self.use_value()`; however, it must remain as `None` in the constructor. The dilemma here is how to properly typehint this situation.

- If I choose to typehint it as shown above, I get an `error: Item "None" of "Optional[MyOtherClass]" has no attribute "used"  [union-attr]`
- If I instead remove the variable definition from the constructor and move the typehint to `self.initialize_value()`, I get an `Instance attribute value defined outside __init__` error from Pylint

What is the best way to go about this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: When I try to import this example code in Python3.9, I don't get the error you are describing.  Additionally, since `MyOtherClass` isn't defined in your example, I can't get this to run.  Can you flesh your example out a bit more and provide steps for reproducing the errors?

Comment: Probably what you should do is write something like `if self.value is None: raise ValueError()` at the start of the `use_value` method. This way you can give a useful error message when your class is used incorrectly, it gives useful information to people who read your code, and MyPy should be able to tell that the variable won't be `None` for the rest of the method (because if it was `None`, it would have raised).

Comment: @morris sorry if it wasn't clear, but the error I described was not an error with Python, but in fact with Pylint - this is solely about best practices, not getting the code to work

Comment: @kaya3 that worked, thanks a lot! I didn't know `mypy` would be able to check type from just an if statement, and that's perfect!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid repetition, when such an attribute is used throughout the class in multiple methods, a common pattern for me is protecting it and defining a property that raises an error, if the attribute behind it is not set:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._value: MyOtherClass | None = None
        self.initialize_value()

    @property
    def value(self) -> MyOtherClass:
        if self._value is None:
            raise AttributeError("...")
        return self._value

    def initialize_value(self):
        self._value = MyOtherClass()

    def use_value(self):
        return self.value.used
```

This also removes ambiguity for the type checker since the return type of the property is *always* `MyOtherClass`.